# Find energy and momentum coefficient($\alpha$ and $\beta$) for laminar flow

Tags: fluid-dynamics

We have laminar flow and the equation of velocity is:

$$U_r=K(R^2-r^2)$$

Where $U_r$ is velocity at radius $r$ and $R$ is radius of the pipe and $K$ is constant.

I tried to draw the figure:[image]

In this figure $(R^2-r^2)$ lies on the shaded area.

$$\alpha=\frac{\int v^3 . dA}{V^3.A}  \quad  \beta=\frac{\int v^2. dA}{V^2.A}$$

So $A=\pi(R^2-r^2)$. But I don't know how to calculate these integrals to find $\alpha$ and $\beta$

Edit: I guess I should use polar system to calculate integral but I don't have the value of $V$ (Which is average velocity)

Comment: Seems very similar to your two previous questions : [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/584475/calculation-of-energy-coefficient-alpha-for-open-channels) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/584401/find-average-velocity-and-energy-and-momentum-coefficient-alpha-and-beta).  Note also that homework-type questions are not allowed and it seems to be the case you are asking for specific problems of a similar type to be solved rather than trying to solve them yourself.

Comment: I tried my best to do the homework and I also showed my work and show where I stuck. instead of just sending the problem without any work and asking to solve them .Also What is the problem of sending different questions on same topic? I am sure the questions are different and need different technic to solve!

Comment: The community on Physics SE have repeatedly voted to make [homework-like](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) and [check-my-work](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093) type questions off topic.  They are probably the biggest reason for questions being  voted to close.  Advice on these type questions is limited to concepts (not specific of problems).  In this case you want hep calculating the integrals, but that (IMO) amounts to providing a worked solution which is something members should not do for homework-like questions.  Those are the rules as I understand them.

Comment: Ok. It is funny, in these kind of situation a lot of users of Math SE downvote the post but here I don't see any downvote:).